# How can I switch tabs in Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

Alt tab switches the tab of the local computer unfortunately. Any workarounds?

Comment: I assume you want to switch the tabs of the remote computer. Doesn't mouse work in this case?

Comment: Yes it would, but I have a CAD software that executes and often hangs in the front window. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Current build of chrome remote desktop web app.

If you go fullscreen you can use alt + tab normally. It captures the keys when in fullscreen only.

[image: fullscreen button]

Comment: this used to work, but seems to be broken in recent versions of chrome and does not work now.

Comment: Also broken for me: tried today Chrome Remote Desktop from Win 10 (v2004) to Mac (v10.14.6) in "Full-screen" mode, with the "Send system keys" checkbox checked, alt+tab goes to Win, not Mac (and I too remember this working in the past). I even tried mapping AltLeft to MetaLeft using "Configure Key Mappings" as another post suggested. At least I can log in and control the Mac today and mapped ControlLeft to MetaLeft which is a god-send! (chrome remote desktop login fluctuated with the "weather" over the last year whether it would let me log in mysteriously with erroneous wrong pin errors)

Comment: Working today, for Chrome Remote Desktop on Win10, remoting to a Linux computer. THank you! Note there are two things that seem to say "full screen." The "Full screen" Icon in the outer window of CRD app (broken rectangle) is the wrong one. Use the "Full screen" tickbox in the CRD menu that appears when you click on the left-pointing chevron at the right side of the screen. Same menu where you click "Send System keys"

Comment: About a month or so ago the 'Send system keys' option seems to have disappeared when remoting to mac. Is it just me?

Answer (score 5):

I use another program to get this functionality: **AutoHotkey**

Then I remapped **Alt+Tab to Alt+A**, Win+D to Alt+D ...

So:

Local computer control:  Alt+Tab; Win+D; Win+R (no change)

Remote computer control: Alt+A; Alt+D; Alt+R (or as you define)

So you install AutoHotkey to your **remote** computer.
Add AutoHotkey script (text file renamed to .ahk) to startup apps
(Win+R shell:startup)

The script (script.ahk) contains this:

```
LAlt & A::AltTab
Return

!R::Send #r
Return

!D::Send #d
Return
```

You can find help on scripting here: [AutoHotkey: DOcumentation: Remapping Keys and Buttons](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

Comment: This is extremely useful. Any idea on how to remap the windows key to something else?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to this, which works on my system...

Press one of the arrow keys before issuing the command you want.

For example, attempting an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> without hitting an arrow key and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> switches the cursor to local, so the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> never goes through to the remote system.  That's what I am seeing here anyhow.

I found that using one of the arrow keys first seems to disable the cursor (so long as there is no cursor activity in the meantime) so the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does the app switching on the remote interface as needed.

Once you have switched to the remote application you need, you can move the cursor with mouse/trackpad/etc. as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I found one can send CTRL Alt Del through Chrome Remote Desktop in the corner dropdown menu, through which I can launch Task Manager, and I can switch to any window.

Answer (score 1):

I use program AutoHot Key too, but on 2 computers: local and remote. 
On the local machine Alt+Tab i remapped to Alt+q 
On the remote machine Alt+q i remapped to Alt+Tab
And! On the local machine i want to use Alt+Tab to other application(s) as previously used
The script on the local machine looks like:

$!Tab::  ; Alt+Tab

If WinActive("Basement - Google Chrome")

```
  Send, !q
```

else

```
Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
```

return

The script on the remote machine (Basement) looks like:

$!q:: Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Tab works when connecting Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. I haven't tried other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows key on your local keyboard and remote desktop is running on Windows, then you can try <kbd>**Win**</kbd> + <kbd>**Tab**</kbd>. You should use arrows keys or mouse to choose the desired tab then.

My config: local OS - Ubuntu 16.04, remote  - Win 10